# How to fetch data from a CSV dataset with javascript for BIRT?

Tags: birt, rhino

I'm trying to make an authorization device for each of my BIRT's reports. 
The goal is to avoid report generation for a non-authorized user.

I'm using **Birt-Viewer**. With javascript, in "BeforeFactory", I want to fetch  user's ID in a simple column of a CVS dataset.
For instance, user's id is `je1234he`. 

CSV dataset contain `je1234he` among ids, so this user is allowed to generate the rapport. If not, the user would obtain nothing.

After many and many hours of search, I still don't know how to fetch an ID through a CSV dataset using javascript in a BeforeFactory event.

In BeforeFactory event, this code get user's id (HTTP_CAS_USER):

```
userID = reportContext.getParameterValue( "parm1" );
reportContext.setGlobalVariable("userID", userID);
```

CSV dataset is:

```
select "userid" from "usrautho.txt" : {"userid","userid",STRING} (Data Source CSV, Data Set CSV).
```

I only perform to do the first step:

```
myDataSet = reportContext.getDesignHandle().findDataSet("Data Set CSV");
```

Now I'd like to fetch "userID" along "myDataSet".

I'd be very glad if someone could help me.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier and more standard to restrict access outside of BIRT, for example by accessing the servlet only through an Apache HTTPD?

Comment: Yes, i've already done it, with apache and a module named "mod-auth-cas". Inside Birt-viewer, with a javascript code, i get http_cas_user.